# insert xml file into sql

Tags: php, sql, xml

I want to insert **Large** xml values into sql using php.

This is xml example :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<contacts>
<con>
  <id>1</id> 
  <name>user_name</name> 
  <city>city_name</city> 
  <street>street_name</street> 
  <phone1>phone_number1</phone1> 
  <phone2>phone_number2</phone2> 
  <phone3 /> 
  <phone4 /> 
  </con>


  <con>
  <id>2</id> 
  <name>user_name</name> 
  <city>city_name</city> 
  <street>street_name</street> 
  <phone1>phone_number1</phone1> 
  <phone2>phone_number2</phone2> 
  <phone3 /> 
  <phone4 /> 
  </con>

    </contacts>
```

I make SQL like this so i want insert the data in it :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_1` text NOT NULL,
  `phone_2` text NOT NULL,
  `phone_3` text NOT NULL,
  `phone_4` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1256 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Can I do this job with php? and how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You insert it as any other data. Have you tried anything? Also accept answers to your questions!

Comment: You can use the DOMDocument extension in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php You can then loop through each node and insert it appropriately.

Comment: Accept answers that fix the questions that you have. Think about your fellow programmers that help you out!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `phone_3` and `phone_4` are NOT NULL in the database, and not set in the XML.

You can do this by parsing the xml in your php code with the [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) ([alternative reference](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php)). After that it's simply inserting them into the database.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use xml function xml_parse_into_struct() to convert your xml into an array than using loop you can insert data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

parse xml file, loop through constructing a sql query for each data, execute query, output some verification such us if query was successfull or not...

Answer (score 0):

As dragon112 mentions you want to parse the XML in your PHP code. A similar question has already been asked and answered. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938362/php-code-import-xml-file-from-web-server-public-html-ctrackxml-into-mysql-d) for some inspiration.

Good luck